# FailedRequestTracing module failed to create directory in azure

Tags: azure

I try to run my Azure site using `SDK1.8` locally.I got a following error in event viewer.

`'\\?\C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\eb8b9108-45c8-4933-8e47-50be3a36cbd9\directory\DiagnosticStore\FailedReqLogFiles\Web\deployment18(154).App.Azure.App_IN_0_Web\'. No logs will be generated until this condition is corrected......`

In browser I got a error:

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
```

In .csdef file i use `physicalDirectory` like this.

```
 <Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\dec31">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
  </Site>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem. Its not a problem about `.csdef` file.Its a problem in my `web.config`

file.There is a frame work conflict.So I modify the `web.config` and its work.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Can you tell what precisely you changed to make this work? Thank in advance.

Comment: @Jan Conflict between framework 3.5 and 4.0 .I rebuild and upgrade all for 4.0 and its work.

Comment: OK, thanks for the speedy reply. I just can't see any configuration in my web.config which points to v3.5... I guess there are other causes for this problem then. Thanks again though.